# How to create a Vector where each entry is a structure with 2 fields

Tags: java, arrays, vector

I am trying to create a data structure in Java that is a Vector into which some information about an unknown number of entities will go from a database. When it comes to this information, I only care about 2 fields. Also, it is required that when I iterate through this Vector, I can extract these two fields (say, String) in pairs. Schematically speaking,

```
String s1 = Vector[1].Field1, String s2 = Vector[1].Field2
```

Is this even possible? Does anyone know a more efficient way to achieve this?

Note: I would like to keep it in a single Vector because I pass it to another class for processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
public class Entry {
    public String field1;
    public String field2;
}

List<Entry> vector = ...;
```

Comment: Does this class need to be instantiated prior to this? Also, is there a special way to add it to the current file? That is, after trying this, it does not seem that my current class "knows" about the Entry class.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using `Map<String, String>` 
But map will be unique keys

Also you can create your own Class and pass it to the `Vector<yourclass>`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it :

Create an object Pair with 2 attributes : field 1, field 2

Add this object to your vector.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Vector of maps, with keys `value1` and `value2`. `Vector<Map<String, String>>`.

Or define a new object with two attributes ( I suggest the second option )

Comment: After I define the new class, do I instantiate it in the variables section of the current class? It seems that the current class does not see the newly defined class.

Comment: @ArtforLife you need to import it, but if you use any IDE it will do the job for you.